# VZW Galaxy S5 can't use Wi-Fi (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET)

Tags: wi-fi

My Verizon Galaxy S5 can connect to my home's Wi-Fi, but I can't load anything once I'm connected. The error message I get is `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`.

Other non-Galaxy smartphones work fine on the network, as does my laptop.

Is this an issue with the phone or the router? Things worked great up until a few weeks ago so I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: you need to reset your ip address. have you tried "forget network" and add the network again ?

Comment: Tried that, but had to reboot for the change to take effect.

Comment: you mean reboot is needed for adding the network again ? Is this rooted phone ? have you installed any APPS that related to wifi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this same issue also with an S5 on Verizon, but I've narrowed down when it happens. If I enable the hot spot then after I disable it, I will get this error when using the browser (Chrome) and apps that need internet are also unable to function.

Once it starts, nothing seems to allow a wifi internet connection to work. The only thing that seems to get rid of the error is restarting the phone.

Comment: Good thing the S7 comes out tomorrow :)